# Nginx hide reason of error in WooCommerce API's response

Tags: nginx, woocommerce-rest-api

If i catch the error from WooCommerce API on dev-server (Xampp, apache) - in Response section of error i see something like this:

```
2023-08-07 15:31:30::The Response: Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response Object
(
    [code:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => 400
    [headers:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [Date] => Mon, 07 Aug 2023 15:31:30 GMT
            [Server] => Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29
            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/7.4.29
            [X-Robots-Tag] => noindex
            [Link] => <http://localhost/DokioShop/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
            [X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
            [Access-Control-Expose-Headers] => X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link
            [Access-Control-Allow-Headers] => Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type
            [Expires] => Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
            [Cache-Control] => no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
            [Allow] => GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
            [Content-Length] => 143
            [Connection] => close
            [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [body:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => {"code":"woocommerce_variation_image_upload_error","message":"Error getting remote image . Error: Invalid URL Provided.","data":{"status":400}}
)
```

As you can see, in a last row i can see a detailed information about a reason of error - "Error getting remote image".
But if I am catching the same error on a prod server with Nginx - I see only this:

```
2023-08-07 15:27:53::The Response: Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response Object
(
    [code:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => 500
    [headers:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
            [date] => Mon, 07 Aug 2023 15:27:53 GMT
            [content-type] => text/html
            [content-length] => 186
        )

    [body:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

)
```

There is no object contained the information about a reason of mistake in this response. This makes it very difficult to know where to look for the error.
How to make the Nginx show error information like Apache?